# Showing data from a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a happy birthday card, so I need to take the data from the form to the birthday card page so how do I transfer information from first div(first div is a form) and show that data in the second div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
      function myfunction(){
                 var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

        if(divelement.style.display === 'none')
           divelement.style.display = 'block';
        else
           divelement.style.display = 'none';
           }
       </script>
    <div>

<style>

    form{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
    <div id="form" style="display:block;" >
        <form name = "form" id = "form">
          First name:<br> <br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname">
          <br><br>
          Last name:<br><br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" ><br><br>
          Message:<br><br>
          <input type="text" name="message" >
          <br><br>
          <button onclick="myfunction('form')">Click me !!!!</button>
        </form> 
    </div>
    </div>

    <div>
```

```
    <div class='card'>
    <div class='front face'>
        <img src= images/birthday.gif/>
    </div>
        <div class="back face">
            <img src= images/birthday1.gif/>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are quite a few things wrong with your code.  Firstly, more often than not, it is always a safe bet to give divs you wish to manipulate IDs as this ensure they are unique and their attributes can be accessed.  Secondly, your argument for myFunction in the onclick event isn't doing anything as the function as it is defined doesn't have any parameters nor are parameters necessary in this case.  Basically the following code will produce an output however you will of course need to tweak accordingly to place information where you so desire.

```
function myFunction() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var lname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");

    var output = fname + lname + message;
    document.getElementById("NAME_OF_OUTPUT_DIV").innerHTML = output;
};
```

Again ensure all inputs have IDs and so does the div you wish to output to.  Cheers.

P.S. You can do some pretty above and beyond stuff with jquery - often much easier too.